# jQuery $.off different selector to original

Tags: jquery

I've added a plugin to bootstrap to enable hover dropdowns and I would like to disable the original click dropdown event handler only for dropdowns that have the hover dropdown enabled (`data-hover="dropdown"`).

The click dropdown event handler is set using

```
$(document).on('click.bs.dropdown', '[data-toggle="dropdown"]', ....
```

How can I do a `$.off` for this event *only* for elements that also have `data-hover="dropdown"`? If I put that in the selector of  `$.off` there is no effect because that is not how the selector was originally defined.

Comment: Why don't you do it this way: `[data-toggle="dropdown"]:not([data-hover="dropdown"])`

Comment: Do you have access to modify the `.on` event binding?

Comment: @Al.G. It's defined in bootstrap javascript that I'd prefer not having to modify.

Comment: don't set `data-toggle` on element is simplest solution

Comment: @charlietfl I forgot to mention that the data-toggle needs to stay if it is a touch device. That is why I need to use `$.off`.

Comment: but you can manually initialize the dropdown also and have more control over it that way

Comment: @charlietfl True, that works. I'll leave the question open out of curiosity but if there is no better answer I'll accept that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this is what you are looking for? [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8qkgq6o/10/). @media with a display block for the hover state and a window size detection to turn off and on the toggle collapse of the dropdown. Hope that helps.

CSS

```
@media( min-width: 768px ) {
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    } 
}
```

JS

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    var windowWidth  = $( window ).width()

    $( window ).resize( function () {
      if ( $( this ).width() !== windowWidth ) {
          dropDownFix()
          windowWidth = $( this ).width()
      } 
    })

    function dropDownFix () {
        if ( windowWidth > 768 ) {
            $( ".dropdown-toggle" ).removeAttr( "data-toggle" )
            $( ".dropdown-toggle" ).attr( "aria-expanded", "false" )
            $( ".dropdown" ).removeClass( "open" )
        } else {
            $( ".dropdown-toggle" ).attr( "data-toggle", "dropdown" )
        }
    }
    dropDownFix()  
})
```

Comment: No, sorry, I was looking specifically for the `$.off` method